# Exception : "Installation incomplete" in Windows 2012 server

Tags: visual-studio

I have an issue with installing a web application (REST service also) in a windows 2012 server. I have created a basic asp.net web site and web setup project for the same. When I tried to install it in a windows 2012 server, installation fails with the "Installation incomplete" exception.

when I tried to write log while installing this msi, I have got the following log file(MainEngineThread is returning 1603), from which I am unable to find the exact reason for this failure.
[image]

```
=== Verbose logging started: 3/27/2014  6:25:05  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:282]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:282]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WebSetup1.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WebSetup1.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WebSetup1.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WebSetup1.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:282]: End dialog not enabled

MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:333]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'WEBCA_TARGETVDIR' 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:333]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETVDIR property. Its value is 'WebSetup1'.
Action ended 6:25:05: WEBCA_TARGETVDIR. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:333]: Doing action: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE
Action 6:25:05: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. 
Action start 6:25:05: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:333]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE' 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:333]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 2756
MSI (c) (84:20) [06:25:05:333]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\MSIF567.tmp, Entrypoint: SetTARGETSITE
MSI (c) (84:14) [06:25:05:333]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (84:14) [06:25:05:333]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (84:14) [06:25:05:333]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (84!34) [06:25:05:361]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 3636
INFO   : [03/27/2014 06:25:05:361] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [03/27/2014 06:25:05:361] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
ERROR  : [03/27/2014 06:25:05:361] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: FAILED:  -2147221164
ERROR  : [03/27/2014 06:25:05:361] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action failed with code: '340'
INFO   : [03/27/2014 06:25:05:361] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '340'
MSI (c) (84!34) [06:25:05:361]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790531 for thread 3636
CustomAction WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (c) (84:20) [06:25:05:361]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 2756
Action ended 6:25:05: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:361]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 6:25:05: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 6:25:05: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:05:361]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:361]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:361]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:361]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:361]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:376]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898.For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (84:C8) [06:25:05:376]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
Action 6:25:05: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (84:04) [06:25:05:376]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 
Action ended 6:25:07: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
Action ended 6:25:07: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:613]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (84:14) [06:25:07:613]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.

Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(C): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000.  Please install Internet Information Server or a newer operating system and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.

=== Logging stopped: 3/27/2014  6:25:07 ===
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Product: WebSetup1 -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: WebSetup1. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (84:C4) [06:25:07:630]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 3/27/2014  6:25:07 ===
```

Can anyone help me to find the reason for this and solve it. I have a wcf rest service also, which is also not getting installed in the new server.

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: FAILED:  -2147221164 is the root problem.  Converting that value to hex produces 0x80040154, the infamous "Class not registered" error code for COM components.  Using SysInternals' Process Monitor can show you which particular {guid} it is looking for, giving a hint to what component is missing.  Googling the {guid} value is usually enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved this issue by Enabling **IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility** from Add roles & Features wizard.

[image]

Please refer the following  for more info...

http://geekswithblogs.net/blomqvist/archive/2010/11/12/the-installer-was-interrupted-before-application-could-be-installed.aspx

Thanks 
Sebastian

Comment: If I can't install IIS 6 Management Compatibility, what can I do? Thanks.